# Sharepoint: DLLs disappearing from the GAC

Tags: sharepoint, dll, sharepoint-2010, gac

I'm fairly new to SharePoint but I'm learning fast. However, I've encountered a confounding issue that has me completely stumped, and the internet hasn't been able to provide anything useful as of yet...

I'm running **SharePoint 2010** in a VM, and I am getting a **repeated issue with *libraries spontaneously disappearing from the GAC***. This is happening on average about once a day at the moment, but at different times of day and with **no apparent trigger**. The VM I am running (and the source code thereon) are identical to my colleagues', yet I am the only one to have encountered this issue. I have **rebuilt my environment several times** and thought I'd cracked it with this latest one, but the issue has just reoccurred. Since it happens at different times of day I don't think it can be a timer job, and it can happen **spontaneously with no user input** (no changes to code, settings, environment, anything).

I can provide more details of the libraries affected if required, although it seems to be a **mixture of proprietary libraries specific to the project, and standard Microsoft assemblies**.

Any help or pointers would be gratefully received!

Comment: Are you deploying the Project using Visual studio directly ?

Comment: The solution is deployed using a custom-written PowerShell script, and completes without error. Everything then works fine for a random period of time before the above issue occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. I fixed it by recompiling one the conflicting dll files with a different version number and some different number. Then i made sure that every webpart that uses this dll had this dll in their individual sharepoint package, then i deployed the webparts again and this time they didnt disappear.

I also found out that disappearing was not random and was the result after another webpart was being installed. Pretty weird.